# enable MFA in Azure AD via programmatic interface

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, adal

Is there any programmatic way to enable user MFA settings in Azure AD?
I know there is a powershell module **MSONLINE**. Unfortunately, my client is a pure linux environment.
Is there any approach, e.g. python sdk or java?

Answer (score 0):

The Azure MFA SDK lets you build two step verifications to sign-in process of applications in you Azure AD tenant. Refer: [GitHub Link](https://github.com/SenthuranSivananthan/azure-mfa-java).

Comment: The MFA SDK has been deprecated and will stop working on Nov. 18, 2018: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-mfa-sdk